# Recommendations for a One to Many (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure out the best way to define a one to many relationship table as it pertains to Customers and Addresses.  Each Customer can have multiple address (Mailing, Billing, Delivery, etc). The Type of address is stored in a separate table (AddressType).

Here's what I have:

```
public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }

  public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
        public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public State State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Display { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
```

Couple of questions ...

1. Would what I have above be considered good practice? If not, how would you define it?
2. Assuming that the AddressType table contains Mailing, Billing and Delivery, how would I issue a Linq query where I only want to pull the Mailing Address?

Thanks a bunch.

--- Val

Comment: Is there some predefined set of address types? If so and those are Mailing, Billing and Delivery only you could use enum property instead of another entity

Comment: Hi @RomanKalinchuk, thanks for the response.  the AddressTypes are in an AddressType table.  The goal was to be able to support any number of address types.  For instance, a company (a Hospital for example) may have many types of delivery addresses (PPE, vs. Food vs. Chemicals, etc.).  I used a separate table for Address and Address Types for that purpose.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a 'base' address class. Mailing, Billing, Delivery etc. would inherit from this base class.

```cs
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }

    public string HouseNumberAddition { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

In case of delivery, you might want to print a delivery note with the address label for the delivery driver. But is does not make sense to include a DeliveryNote in the base address class, because when would a billing address need a delivery note?

So you inherit from your base Address class to create specific address types.

For example:

```cs
public class DeliveryAddress : Address
{
    public string DeliveryNote { get; set; } = "Please don't ring the bell after 10pm."
}
```

Assuming you use EF Code First, Entity framework creates an `Address` table, with a `discriminator` column. When you save a new address, the `discriminator` column defines the type of address.

```cs
var googleCompany = new Company
{
    DeliveryAddress = new DeliveryAddress
    {
        Street = "Google Street",
        HouseNumber = 1,
        DeliveryNote = "Watch out for the dog."
    },
    CompanyAddress = new CompanyAddress()
};

var microsoftCompany = new Company
{
    DeliveryAddress = new DeliveryAddress
    {
        Street = "Microsoft Street",
        HouseNumber = 2,
        DeliveryNote = "Don't bring an Apple device on the premise."
    },
    CompanyAddress = new CompanyAddress()
};


_context.Companies.Add(googleCompany);
_context.Companies.Add(microsoftCompany);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Now to query the companies and specify the type of address you need, you just need to make a call to `include` and let EF Core include the address.

```cs
var companiesWithBothDeliveryAddress = 
    _context.Companies.Include(x => x.CompanyAddress)
                      .Include(x => x.DeliveryAddress).ToList();

var companiesWithOnlyDeliveryAddress =
    _context.Companies.Include(x => x.DeliveryAddress).ToList();
```

The EF Fluent API configuration should be something like this:

```cs
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // Company to CompanyAddress, without inverse property on CompanyAddress.
            builder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasOne(x => x.CompanyAddress)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Company>(x => x.CompanyAddressId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            // Company to DeliveryAddress, without inverse property on DeliveryAddress.
            builder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasOne(x => x.DeliveryAddress)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Company>(x => x.DeliveryAddressId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            // We let all the Address types share the 'CompanyId' column, 
            // otherwise, EF would create a seperate CompanyId column for all of them.
            builder.Entity<Address>()
                .Property(x => x.CompanyId)
                .HasColumnName(nameof(Address.CompanyId));

            builder.Entity<CompanyAddress>()
                .Property(x => x.CompanyId)
                .HasColumnName(nameof(Address.CompanyId));            
            
            builder.Entity<DeliveryAddress>()
                .Property(x => x.CompanyId)
                .HasColumnName(nameof(Address.CompanyId));

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        public DbSet<DeliveryAddress> DeliveryAddresses { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CompanyAddress> CompanyAddresses { get; set; }
```

The result would look like this:

Address Table (I left out some columns for conciseness)

[image]

Companies Table (I left out some columns for conciseness)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Dennis.  What you're saying makes sense except for the lookup  portion.  Since all three address types inherit from the base address, all three have the same attributes (+ extra column for delivery note for delivery address only).  I'll be adding a reference to the AddressType table to identify the type of address. How would I return an IQueryable of Companies with only the AddressType of Mailing? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi @Val you don't need an AddressType table. Because your derived DeliveryAddress class, **is** the 'address type'.  I'll complete the example for your, including EF configuration.

Comment: Hey @Dennis    thank you so very much for the very concise and detailed example.  It's making sense somewhat; I just need to look at it more when my head is more rested.  I'm new to C#, EF, ASP, HTML and there's so much to learn.  I really do appreciate you taking the time to help me out.  Have an awesome day!